# PHP array printing using a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

If I know the length of an array, how do I print each of its values in a loop?

Comment: You don't need to book-keep the length of the array to iterate over it

Answer (score 128):

```
$array = array("Jonathan","Sampson");

foreach($array as $value) {
  print $value;
}
```

or

```
$length = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  print $array[$i];
}
```

Comment: Note that the for() loop doesn't work on arrays with string indexes (obviously)

Comment: Count should be precalculated. In your example, it's being calculated on every loop. It should be:

for ($i = 0, $count = count($array); $i < $count; $i++)

Answer (score 13):

Use a foreach loop, it loops through all the key=>value pairs:

```
 foreach($array as $key=>$value){
     print "$key holds $value\n";
 }
```

Or to answer your question completely:

```
 foreach($array as $value){
     print $value."\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

for using both things  variables value and kye

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
 print "$key holds $value\n";
}
```

for using variables value only

```
foreach($array as $value){
 print $value."\n";
}
```

if you want to do something repeatedly until equal the length of array us this

```
// for loop
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
 // do something with $array[$i]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is example:

```
$array = array("Jon","Smith");
foreach($array as $value) {
  echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 4):

I also find that using `<pre></pre>` tags around your var_dump or print_r results in a much more readable dump.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) echo $key, ' => ', $value;
```

Answer (score 2):

either foreach:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  // do something with $key and $value
}
```

or with for:

```
for($i = 0, $l = count($array); $i < $l; ++$i) {
  // do something with $array[$i]
}
```

obviously you can only access the keys when using a foreach loop.

if you want to print the array (keys and) values just for debugging use `var_dump` or `print_r`

Answer (score 1):

```
while(@$i++<count($a))
echo $a[$i-1];
```

[3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LsN83)

Answer (score 1):

Another advanced method is called an `ArrayIterator`. It’s part of a wider `class` that exposes many accessible `variables` and `functions`. You are more likely to see this as part of `PHP` classes and heavily `object-oriented` projects.

```
$fnames = ["Muhammed", "Ali", "Fatimah", "Hasan", "Hussein"];

$arrObject = new ArrayObject($fnames);
$arrayIterator = $arrObject->getIterator();

while( $arrayIterator->valid() ){
echo $arrayIterator->current() . "<br />";
$arrayIterator->next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're debugging something and just want to see what's in there for *your* [the print_f function](https://www.php.net/print_r) formats the output nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you are debugging as Tom mentioned, you can use [var_dump](https://www.php.net/var_dump) to see the array.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach before foreach: :)

```
reset($array); 
while(list($key,$value) = each($array))
{
  // we used this back in php3 :)
}
```