# Searching value in array and comparing / getting next and previous values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array `$arr` looking like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["food"]=>
    string(5) "Toast"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "28"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["food"]=>
    string(5) "Pizza"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "45"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["food"]=>
    string(5) "Steak"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "33"
  }
}
```

I also have a variable `$curr_age = 45;`.

Now I am looking for a way to search through the array until I find `$arr[$i]["age"] = $curr_age` and then stop.
Also, how do I get the food from the next & previous arrays (Toast and Steak in the example)?

For searching through the array, I have this code:

```
$i = 0;

foreach( $arr as $array ){ 

    if( $curr_age == $arr[$i]["age"] ) {

        $next = $arr[$i++]["food"];
        $prev = $arr[$i--]["food"];

    }

    $i++;

 }
```

As you can probably imagine, this is not working as expected and I have no idea why. One thing that strikes me though is the fact that the `foreach` loop is actually only used to increment `$i` and that `$array` is never used, but I can't get my head around how to fix this or how to perform the task mentioned above in general.

I think I already found out that there is no "built in" way in PHP to do this, an extra function is needed, but again: I have no clue what that function needs to do. I am not even sure if this statement is true.

I already tried `array_search` and then simply increment/decrement the key by 1, but that didn't work for two reasons I believe. First it seems that `array_search` can't handle that type of array & second, the keys can be non-consecutive, so doing `$x++` or `$x--` doesn't seem right.

Comment: one problem that i think is $arr. Put $array in place of $arr in if condition and statements inside if condition

Comment: your question look like unseen passage.question should be short.i think foreach($arr as $keys=>$values)like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array indexes are already numeric so there's not really a need to also maintain an incrementing index, just use the key assignment in the foreach loop, and make sure you test the previous and next keys actually exist before trying to access them

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['age'] == $curr_age) {
        if (isset($arr[$k-1])) {
            $prev = $arr[$k-1];
        }
        if (isset($arr[$k+1])) {
            $next = $arr[$k+1];
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$length = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  if( $curr_age == $array[$i]["age"] ) {
    if (i<$length){
        $next = $array[$i+1]["food"];
    }
    if (i>0){
        $prev = $array[$i-1]["food"];
    }
  }
}
```

[Answer for looping an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293896/php-array-printing-using-a-loop) + your code = Solved.
As Mark Baker noted, the arrays might get a wrong value if they are not checked before assignment.

Comment: Test for age being matched by either the first and last entries in the array, else your $prev or $next respectively will error

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Compare the element assigned by foreach at particular position ($array here) to compare instead of $arr[$i]["age"]

```
$i=0;

foreach($arr as $array)
{
    if($array['age'] == $curr_age)
    {
        $Previous = $arr[$i-1]['food'];
        $Next = $arr[$i+1]['food'];
        break;
    }

    $i++;
}
```