# Reading array data from to element

Tags: php, arrays

Alright so I am trying to achieve something but I am not sure how to do it. I am basically trying to read From-To array. Basically lets say that this is my array

```
$arr = array("a","b","c","d","e","f");

    foreach($arr as $a) {
        echo $a;
    }
```

I want to be able to read stuff from B to E. How do I achieve that?

Also I'd want to be able to reverse that, so for example I read from F to C (it would then show F,E,D,C)

I googled a bit but couldnt find any matching results for this.

EDIT: I am not trying to ask how to print all values from an array, I am asking how to reverse them, so I can for example read from 9th element to 1st element of the array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array printing using a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293896/php-array-printing-using-a-loop)

Comment: I didnt say I want to print an array, I know how to do it. Read before you post please.

Comment: If you actually read the whole post, you would find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293909/2679529), which explains how to use the `for` statement to loop from a starting to an ending index, i.e., `for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { print $array[$i]; }`. That makes easy to deduce that in order to start from the second element, use `for ($i = 1; ...` instead of `for ($i = 0; ...`.

Comment: If `for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)` goes from the first to the last element in `$arr`, then `for ($i = count($arr) - 1; $i > 0; $i--)` loops from the last to the first element. That said, do your calculations and _voilà_, there's your loop. If you want to _dinamically_ find the index of an element that matches a specific condition, then please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo here](https://eval.in/683320)

if you want to output the upper char use strtoupper() function and array_map() function.

```
<?php
$arr = array("a","b","c","d","e","f");
array_walk(array_slice($arr, 1, count($arr)-2), function($value){echo $value."\n";});
array_walk(array_slice(array_reverse($arr), 0, count($arr)-2), function($value){echo $value."\n";});
```