# How can i get multiple value from POST variable using same name

Tags: php, post, input

When user inputs text in 'ctext' field and press accept, I want to fill the value=" " field with user input, i achieved this but it fills all the value fields of same name in the page, how can i achieve it for different value of different ctext input? Anyone please give me solution with example, Many thanks

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root123', 'font');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM pens ORDER by id ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if($result):
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0):
        $i=0;
        while( $pen = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ):
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?action=add&id=<?php echo $pen['id']; ?>">

            <div class="name pen-<?php echo $pen['id']; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="ctext[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your text here" value="<?php $ctext = false; if(isset($_POST['ctext'])){ $ctext = $_POST['ctext']; } echo $ctext[$i]; ?>"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $pen['id']?>"></input>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-custom">
                <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-block" value="Accept"></input>
            </div>      
        </form>
        <?php
        $i++;
        endwhile;
    endif;
endif;
```

?>

Comment: What you want to do is not clear

Comment: when user give inputs i want to fill the fields with their inputs, so i want the value to be filled dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand what you want. You want to access the `ctext` for each individual `$pen` when printing the corresponding form.

You just need to name your `<input>` with a unique name and then access that value when printing. A possible solution is this:

```
<input type="text" name="ctext[<?php echo $pen['id']; ?>]" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your text here" value="<?php $ctext = ''; if(isset($_POST['ctext'][$pen['id']])){ $ctext = $_POST['ctext'][$pen['id']]; } echo $ctext; ?>"></input>
```

What does it do?

- `name="ctext[<?php echo $pen['id']; ?>]"` ensures a unique name for each `$pen`. For a `$pen` with `id` 1 this will result in `name="ctext[1]"`.
- `if(isset($_POST['ctext'][$pen['id']])){ $ctext = $_POST['ctext'][$pen['id']]; }` uses `$pen['id']` to look up the corresponding value in `$_POST['ctext']`.

By the way, when outputting user input you should always escape it, e.g. with `htmlspecialchars`. This will look like this: `echo htmlspecialchars($ctext);` That way malicious input like `"><script>alert('Hello!')</script>` won't execute the javascript.

**Update**: as requested a solution using session to store data:

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root123', 'font');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM pens ORDER by id ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if($result):
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0):
        session_start();
        if (isset($_POST['ctext'])) {
            $_SESSION['ctext'][$_POST['id']] = $_POST['ctext'];
        }
        while( $pen = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ):
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?action=add&id=<?php echo $pen['id']; ?>">

            <div class="name pen-<?php echo $pen['id']; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="ctext" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your text here" value="<?php $ctext = ''; if(isset($_SESSION['ctext'][$pen['id']])){ $ctext = $_SESSION['ctext'][$pen['id']]; } echo htmlspecialchars($ctext); ?>"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $pen['id']?>"></input>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-custom">
                <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-block" value="Accept"></input>
            </div>      
        </form>
        <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
endif;
```

Note: I removed the now unnecessary counter `$i`. The session handling is mainly done before the `while` loop (start a session and store POST data). During output the values from the session are used. The name of the input is not an array anymore.

Comment: it works when i add pen[1], but when i add pen[2], pen[1] value erase, can i store pen[1] input value even if i add pen[2]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking with that question. This code keeps the ids in sync with your database, so yes, if there is no `pen[1]` but a `pen[2]`, it still works for `pen[2]`.

Comment: actually i want to display the user input after they press accept buttons, so when user inputs text and press accept for first item, input will be displayed in textfield, then when user inputs text in second field and press accept for second item, inputs for both first & second item will be displayed in textfield, but now with this code, after pressing second item's accept button, first item's input value get lost, can i show both inputs?

Comment: Your problem now is that you don't store the user input and have a different `<form>` for each of your pens. As each of your `<form>` has a `action` depending on `$pen['id']` I'm not sure this is solvable without storing the values on the server, e.g. the session. If possible, you can however move the `<form>` outside the loop, so your resulting HTML contains only one `<form>`, then all your values should be available.

Comment: i was thinking using session, would you please show me example how can i achieve that?

Comment: i tried the updated code but the session variable didn't save the value

Comment: Yepp, found the error. The hidden input didn't have a value because of a missing `echo`. I added it to above code.

Comment: worked :) this is exactly what i wanted, marked your answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

Change name of an input to an array.like this . When you submit the form you will get these values as an array. Give it a try

```
<input type="text" name="ctext[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your text here"></input>
```

Comment: I did try, but how to print those array inside value?  would you please show me the code inside value?

Comment: the most case you can use array input in multiple choose elements like select.
try SELECT2 jquery plugin
or you can use a splitter in values for example semi-colon

Comment: @ArRafi `print_r($_POST['ctext']) ` will give print of the value

Comment: @payam Select2.js is it for select option you can't use with text input field

Comment: @user7747472 would you please show me the code inside value=" "

Comment: Can u give print of $pen and show the response maybe then I can help  u with

Comment: I mean this http://jsfiddle.net/qq3fc689/ and this https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is misleading you, your form is in while loop so once any of the **ctext** input is filled your variable **$_POST['ctext']** is set on server side and according to your code it sets all the value of **ctext** once accept is pressed.

You can have different names as a solution or an array indexing in input field **name=“ctext[]”** to avoid this.

Comment: Yes understood, how can i print those array inside value? would you please show me the code inside value?

Comment: [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293896/php-array-printing-using-a-loop)

Comment: i mean i dont wanna print all the values in same field using array, wanna print just values related to the each input

Comment: Initialise a variable $i = 0 outside while loop and do $i++ just before while loop ends. Thus you will have your index in $i. Now read $ctext = $_POST['ctext'] and just echo $ctext[$i] inside your value="" .

Comment: worked for first input, but didn't work for second input

Comment: Try rendering one form instead of many forms on single page, When submit button is pressed only one form will be submitted.